# How to do something like border-top-left-color. [CSS]

Tags: html, css

I want to colour a border but the only options available are `border-left-color`, `border-right-color`, border-top-color`and border-bottom-color` I want to color the bottom, right border of a circle but I can't seem to find it anywhere?

Please ask if I am not making sense as I am not good at explaining things.

One example [here](http://store.apple.com/us/buy-iphone/iphone6) Notice the button in the bottom if the iPhone; notice the shine.

Comment: Yeah I'm a little confused on exactly what you're asking? You're only wanting a quarter of a circles border coloured?

Comment: Yes A quarter of a circle

Comment: Do you want to be able to colour each quarter of the circle or just the bottom right quarter?

Comment: I want to colour just the bottom right quarter.

Comment: Ok, are you wanting to colour the entire bottom right quarter or just the border around the edge?

Comment: I want to colour just the border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a possible approach:

The trick is using `transform: rotate(45deg);` with `border-left-color`.

```css
#thing {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-left-color: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="thing"></div>
```

[**Fiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/chimos/85npvasf/)